# Is a single decoupling capacitor for multiple Vdd lines adequate?

Tags: microcontroller, capacitor, microprocessor, decoupling-capacitor, signal-integrity

The image is taken from the RK3399 datasheet.

Here you can see that a 10uF decoupling capacitor is connected to 13 VDD lines.

Is it a good idea to connect one single decoupling capacitor for all lines?

As I understand it, connecting individual decoupling capacitors to each pin is better because pins which are far away from the decoupling capacitor won't get transient current as fast as the pins  which are closer to the decoupling capacitor.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure there aren't more caps connected to net VDD_CPU_B somewhere else in the schematic?

Comment: You should probably have a few smaller caps (0.1 uF or less) near the Vdd pins, as well as the 10 uF.

Comment: Please link the exact data sheet you got the schematic from.

Comment: The chipis a 32X32 ball grid array. There are more than  100 power and ground pins. Decoupling layout will require significant research. to get it right. If several power pins are adjacent, then a single larger capacitor may be acceptabl. If the power pins occupy a region, then several capacitors in parallel may be required. The presented diagram is not found in the [datasheet](https://www.rockchip.fr/RK3399%20datasheet%20V1.8.pdf) .